# Vector Erase by Iterator Location

Tags: c++, loops, if-statement, vector, iterator

Here I have a vector containing a list of what it thinks are prime numbers, however, some of the later values are divisiable by some values that appear earlier in the list.

To amend this, I tried to iterate around my vector v, and delete the value if it could be divided by another in the vector with no remainder.

However I keep getting this error ("No matching member function to call for erase") and can't think of any other way to delete the value that my iterator points at through this loop. Any suggestions?

```
for (vector<int>::iterator it2 = v.begin();it2 != v.end(); ++it2){
    for (vector<int>::iterator it3 = v.begin();it3 != v.end(); ++it3){
        if (*it3%*it2 == 0){
            v.erase (*it2);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `vector::erase` invalidates iterators...

Comment: And `v.front() % v.front() == 0` so you will have an empty vector at the end.

Comment: I tried v.erase(it2) @AndreasVennström, but now there is no console output. I think that's just erasing the iterator as opposed to the value it points at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`vector::erase` takes an *iterator*. So you need:

```
v.erase(it2);
```

In addition to that, `vector::erase` invalidates iterators and references at or after the point of the erase, including the `end()` iterator, so you need to update your iterators:

```
if (*it3 % *it2 == 0) {
    auto it3index = it3 - v.begin();
    it2 = v.erase(it2);
    it3 = v.begin() + it3index;
}
```

Or you could make the whole thing a lot simpler by not using iterators:

```
for (unsigned i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i) {
    for (unsigned j = 0; j < v.size(); ++j) {
        if (v.at(j) % v.at(i) == 0) {
            v.erase(v.begin() + i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean handle it3?

Comment: Update it since `erase` might invalidate it.

Comment: I'm currently trying to use that 'for' loop you added. It's working, but not quite giving the result I need. I reckon I could use that with a bit of tweaking though! Thanks

Comment: There is a logical error in both iterator-based and index-based solutions. The inner loop must start from (i+1), otherwise all numbers are deleted because they are divisible by themselves.